# How can I use square brackets in Grails Doc's markdown language?

Tags: grails, textile

I am new to Grails Doc's Textile-like markdown language and I am trying to denote an array of a class ContestPool as `[ContestPool]`, but Grails doc attempts to make that a link. How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape brackets with backslashes

```
\[ContestPool\]
```